# How to change ansible verbosity level without changing the command line arguments?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to control the verbosity of ansible playbooks using an environment variable or a global configuration item. This is because ansible is called from multiple places in multiple ways and I want to change the logging level for all further executions from the same shell session.

I observed that if I configure `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=true` ansible will run in debug mode but debug more is extremely verbose and I am only looking for something similar to the `-vvv` option (DEBUG is more verbose than even `-vvvv` option)

I tried to look for a variable inside https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/constants.py but I wasn't able to find one this fits the bill.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure why I missed to answer this, since a long time ago ansible fully supports `ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY=[0|1|2|3|4]`.

For reference, [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-verbosity)

Comment: Is this an environment variable?  Is this a setting in a file?  More info would be nice

Comment: It is an environment variable. It needs to be exported.

Answer (score 8):

I see two ways to do this:

### alias

`alias ansible-playbook="echo 'This is -vv alias'; ansible-playbook -vv"`

This way your shell will call `ansible-playbook -vv` when you type `ansible-playbook` (and print friendly reminder about alias).

### callback plugin

Drop this code as `verbosity_env.py` file into `callback_plugins` directory:

```
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
import os

try:
    from __main__ import display
except ImportError:
    display = None

class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):

    def v2_playbook_on_start(self, playbook):
        v = os.environ.get('ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY')
        if v and display:
            display.display('Verbosity is set to {} with environment variable.'.format(v), color='blue')
            display.verbosity = int(v)
```

It is not production quality code, but does the job. This will check `ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY` environment variable and set display verbosity with its value.

Comment: Thanks, for the moment I raise it as a bug at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22087 because using a callback would not work for me because we already have custom callbacks in use.

Comment: I am trying to look for a way to transform this into a CR on ansible, seems like the right way to implement this feature. I don't fancy adding and maintaining custom callbacks in many projects. We use ansible a lot and it would be a nightmare to add another one, I still have flashbacks about the debug / human_log module.

Answer (score 2):

You can create/edit `ansible.cfg` file in the local folder and add in section `[defaults]`:

```
[defaults]
verbosity=4
```

Alternatively you can add the same option in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find it documented anywhere other than sorin's answer, but if you set `ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY=[0|1|2|3|4]` environment variable, ansible-playbook will pick this up and use it, unless you specify the verbosity on the command line.
E.g. in Unix-type shells:

```
export ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY=2
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml
```

I only stumbled upon it because I tried setting `ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY='-vv'` in a pipeline and Ansible started moaning about it not being an integer!

Comment: Well, to me it looks pretty well documented: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-verbosity